# Not earning Critic

Tags: bug, down-votes

I've already casted 2 downvotes and I'm still not earning Critic: "First down vote". Hope this will help:

[image: Casted 2 downvotes already]

There are 2 downvotes cast already for my votes cast. What's wrong with the system?

Is this a bug or something that I have to wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You have the badge now](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic?userid=20912).

It just takes some time for a badge-awarding task to run. There are tasks for various badges running at different intervals; some badges are more computationally expensive to verify than others. Critic is pretty easy, but still not instantaneous.